# Azure Functions locally "The system cannot find the file specified" during TypeScriptCompiler.CompileAsync()

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm running the azure tools locally in VS Code and Node 8.9.3 with a Typescript 2.6.2 Azure Function created with "func new".  I had to add `"scriptFile": "index.ts",` to function.json to even get it this far - otherwise it complained that it couldn't find the main script.  But now it DOES seem to succeed in all its registrations - 404ing appropriately on non-existent routes, but it emits this when I POST to it with Postman or GET from a browser:

```
{
    "id": "952c0946-bd72-49e7-9f25-c3a8ba8ca236",
    "requestId": "954642f2-9b17-43a2-b26f-b63615360301",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Exception while executing function: Functions.CreateAccount -> The system cannot find the file specified",
    "errorDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.CreateAccount ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The system cannot find the file specified
        at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
        at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
        at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.Node.TypeScript.TypeScriptCompiler.CompileAsync(String inputFile,TypeScriptCompilationOptions options)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.Node.TypeScript.TypeScriptCompilation.CompileAsync(??)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.Node.TypeScript.TypeScriptCompilation.CompileAsync(??)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.Node.TypeScript.TypeScriptCompilationService.GetFunctionCompilationAsync(FunctionMetadata functionMetadata)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.ConditionalJavaScriptCompilationService.GetFunctionCompilationAsync(FunctionMetadata functionMetadata)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.CompileAndTraceAsync(LogTargets logTargets,Boolean throwOnCompilationError,Boolean suppressCompilationSummary)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1.GetFunctionTargetAsync[T](Int32 attemptCount)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.GetFunctionTargetAsync()
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) 
        End of inner exception
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(??)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.FunctionRequestInvoker.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken,WebScriptHostManager scriptHostManager,WebHookReceiverManager webHookReceiverManager)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(??)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpRequestManager.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,Func`3 processRequestHandler,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at async System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

Typescript works fine locally for other things.  Anyone else hit this error?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Azure Functions can recognize the Typescript file. You may need to compile your ts code into javascript via `tsc` command before you run it.

You could follow this doc to compile and run it as well:
https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/TypeScriptCosmosSpike#compile-typescript

Comment: Thanks for this.  Maybe you're right, but there are a few indications that typescript should work:  1) The [known issues docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Azure-Functions-runtime-2.0-known-issues#functional-gaps) for the 2.0 runtime say that Typescript *hasn't yet been migrated*.  2) [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#publish) says you have to *opt-in* to 2.x runtime.  3) The stack trace of the exception does involve typescript compilation, so it seems to know what it needs to do.

Comment: Oh, and 4) the azure cli `func new` offers typescript as a language choice.

Comment: Functions team member here. Functions does have TypeScript support in preview, but we've discussed deprecating it. You can't supply your own tsconfig.json so you haven't to make sure you set it up exactly right, which is kind of a hassle. It's better to transpile to JS beforehand and control the configuration yourself, in my experience. Overall I think us transpiling the TS hasn't paid off as being easier due to the quirks.